# Be encouraged to give. Participate in SE's charity drive

Tags: discussion

SE is running a sort of charity drive. In the spirit of Christian giving, I want to encourage this community to participate.

[Announcing Our Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321399/212646)

Comment: I already [posted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321758/380710), but that was from a prompt at RPG.SE from a christian friend.  Thanks for the alert, Fred.